# Appending big.Int in loop to slice unexpected result

Tags: go

The following Go program produces 1,2,3,4 in followed by 5,5,5,5.  I was expecting 1,2,3,4 in both cases.  What am I doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func primesLessThan(n *big.Int) (primes []big.Int) {
    var one big.Int
    one.SetInt64(1)
    var i big.Int
    i.SetInt64(1)
    for i.Cmp(n) < 0 {
        fmt.Println(i.String())
        primes = append(primes, i)
        i.Add(&i, &one)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    primes := primesLessThan(big.NewInt(5))
    for _, p := range primes {
        fmt.Println(p.String())
    }
}
```

Update: the following code snippet illustrates the unexpected side effects of the shallow copy described in the responses.  The output of the following snippet is 3, 3

```
one := big.NewInt(1)
two := big.NewInt(2)

one = two // Shallow copy. Question: how do I do a deep copy?

one.SetInt64(3) // Side-effect: also changes two

fmt.Println(one.String())
fmt.Println(two.String())
```

Comment: Ignore the function name "primesLessThan"

Comment: replace one = two to one.Set(*two)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the way the object stores its internal data.

Take this example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type foo struct {
    value int
}

func bar() (r []foo) {
    var f foo
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        f.value = i
        r = append(r, f)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    for _, v := range bar() {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

The output will be the expected

```
{0}
{1}
{2}
{3}
{4}
```

The issue in your example is that big.Int stores its value in a slice, and slices are pointers. So when a copy of a big.Int is created, the new copy contains a new pointer to the same slice in memory. A shallow copies is created rather than a deep copy.

See https://golang.org/src/math/big/int.go?s=388:468#L8 for how `bit.Int` is declared, then see https://golang.org/src/math/big/nat.go#L25 for how `nat` is declared.

Here is a solution that uses big.Int

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func primesLessThan(n *big.Int) (primes []big.Int) {
    var one big.Int
    one.SetInt64(1)
    var i big.Int
    i.SetInt64(1)
    for i.Cmp(n) < 0 {
        var result big.Int
        result.Set(&i)
        fmt.Println(result.String())
        primes = append(primes, result)
        i.Add(&i, &one)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    primes := primesLessThan(big.NewInt(5))
    for _, p := range primes {
        fmt.Println(p.String())
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the proper / recommended way to create a deep copy of a big.Int?  The only "constructor" I see in the documentation (https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) is NewInt which takes an int64 argument.  I don't see a "copy constructor" which takes a big.Int argument.  Maybe my thinking is too polluted by years of C++.

Comment: Unfortunately in golang there is no standard deepcopy solution, The correct way to solve this specific is to use the interface to big.Int and not try to treat it like a single value. Instead of `=` use https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Set , In your original example you could have just created a new one inside the for loop scope, called `Set` on it and appended that. I added an example to that in my answer. Please accept the answer if it answers all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The @GarMan solution is fine but you can do simpler doing the string conversion at the `append()` level for `primes []string`:

```
primes = append(primes, i.String())
```

Answer (score -2):

*What we see...* Your primes []big.Int is acting like an array of pointers. By storing i in each slot of primes you are essentially storing the exact same pointer in each spot. That's why it's printing 5 four times.

*Why we see this...* Due to the internals of big.Int, each strict object of big.Int has an internal slice. Slices are implemented as pointers because they are really just fancy arrays. So, while you may have a big.Int object, the object has a pointer to a slice.

When copying a big.Int object you are copying this internal slice pointer.

@GarMan is right and I also agree it has to do with shallow vs. deep copies.

Comment: Apologies for my newbie Go questions.  Why is "[]big.Int" a slice of pointers?  I would have expected it to be a slice of big.Int values.  If I wanted a slice of pointers I would have said "[]*big.Int".  I know I have it wrong, just trying to understand to logic of Go.

Comment: A big.Int is an object, not a standard value. Thus it's a pointer. The go docs are good at explaining pointers. Try effective go.

Comment: This is incorrect, []big.Int is not an array of pointers, it's an array of structs. The structs themselves happen to contain a pointer and when the structs are copied the data they point to is not copied. This is a side effect of the contents of big.Int and not a misunderstanding by Cayle.

Comment: @GarMan your answer is much more accurate than mine. I will edit mine so it is not wrong.

Comment: @GarMan Is it normal in Go to have shallow copy semantics when you copy an object?  Does Go not have something similar to a C++ copy constructor that would allow deep copy semantics to be implemented?  Being used to C++, doing shallow copies for objects seems dangerous to me and it seems to "leak" details about the internal implementation of the object.